# Are there any free Project Management CMS solutions which can interact with SVN and have a nice GUI?

Tags: svn, user-interface, content-management-system, project-management

Are there any free Project Management CMS solutions which can interact with SVN and have a nice GUI (not Trac)?

Comment: I'm curious as to what problems you are having with Trac - everyone that I've seen with your needs turns to Trac and has no complaints.

Comment: @Thomas: It's apparently a hell to set up but one of the nicest tools I had the joy of working with.

Comment: @Johannes It's hell to set up from source, but if you're running a recentish version of Ubuntu, it's `apt-get install trac`. :-D

Comment: @Johannes: I had it set up and working in under half an hour on Debian. It might be painful to setup "on your own" though.

Comment: Trac is a "one installation per project" which can be a bit painful.

Comment: Makis: That's wrong. You can have one trac installation with a lot of projects. Actually that's the way trac is meant to be used.

Comment: ceejayoz: Why is trac hard to set up from source? You install three common packages (Genshi, setuptools, pysqlite) which are in your distro for sure) and then install trac on top. Integration with your web server is the same as every Python application. Why is this hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Redmine. It has some basic integration with Subversion and the GUI is pretty nice.

http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Features

Comment: Redmine is pretty nice and can be installed directly from the Ubuntu repo.